# Magento Product View Details Not loading Properly

Tags: magento-1.9, product, product-view

In my magento website, whenever i am trying to view the product details page,its not loading the product details page properly,after the Product Image its not displaying anything.

**Solution:**

The problem has been resolved by increase the memory size .
ex: 'ini_set('memory_limit', '128M');'

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Magento SE, there might be server error in your case. Please go through your Magento logs file and also check your server error.log file it will help you for further troubleshoot

Comment: If the page stops loading, this is usually due to a PHP error. Check your webservers error logs, or if you have developer mode activated "view source" in the browser to see the error message

Comment: @JayeshPatel i've check my server error.log file and display this message ( Allowed memory size ).any idea about that ?. thank you in advanced.

Comment: @fschmengler  in the browser not see an error message displaying, and i've check Magento log file no error has display. thank you in advanced. any idea plz ?.

Comment: Not the Magento error logs, the web server error logs. It depends on your server where you find them, could be `/var/log/apache2/error.log` for example

Comment: Try to increase value of `memory_limit` variable in your `php.ini`.

Comment: My problem has been resolved by increase value of `memory_limit ` variable thank you in advanced

Comment: @mahmoudismail Post answer in answer section. dont add it in question. I have added answer below question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this Issue following way.

**1: Modify php.ini**

Edit `php.ini` .Search **memory_limit** in your `php.ini`, and change the value of it. If no `memory_limit` found, add the following line at the end of `php.ini`

```
memory_limit = 128M ; /* Change the 128M to your needs */
```

**2 : htaccess Way**

Find the ".htaccess" in your root directory of the specified domain, if there isn't, create one. Put the following line in it.

```
php_value memory_limit 128M; /* Change the 128M to your needs */
```

**3: Change Memory At Runtime**

PHP memory limit could be changed at runtime. Via this way, you have no need to change and configuration of your server environment.

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '128M'); /* Change the 128M to your needs */
```

Hope this helps you